# Array Keeps Being Populated With Only One Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am brand new to Javascript so please excuse me if I am missing something very basic here. I have some code that reads a JSON file and it is supposed to populate an array with each unique year and the number of times that year appears. With my console testing I can see the "filler" object are all correct, but the "counter" array just contains duplicates of the last year and count. For example I'll have

```
 {Year:1970, Count:3}<br>
 {Year:1971, Count:1}<br>
 {Year:1973, Count:2}<br>
 ... <br>
 etc. <br>
```

being printed to the console during the loop, but an array of

```
0: {Year: 2015, Count: 1}<br>
1: {Year: 2015, Count: 1}<br>
2: {Year: 2015, Count: 1}<br>
3: {Year: 2015, Count: 1}<br>
4: {Year: 2015, Count: 1}<br>
...<br>
```

being printed out at the end. I think maybe this has to do with the way `.push()` returns the array or because of where I have variables declared but I really don't know.
Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```js
var cnt = 1;
var counter = [];
var i;
fetch('SomeURL', {
    method: 'GET'
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    var filler = {};
    var current = null;
    var years = [];

    //Populate Year Array
    for (i = 1; i < json.length; i++) {
      years[i - 1] = json[i].Year

    }

    years.sort();
    current = years[0];
    //If the next entry in the array is different from the previous 
    //entry add a new object to the counter array
    for (i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
      if (years[i] != current) {
        current = years[i];
        filler["Year"] = current;
        filler["Count"] = cnt;
        console.log(filler);
        counter.push(filler)
        cnt = 1;
      } else {
        cnt++;
      }
    };
    console.log(counter)
  });
```

Comment: You only create a new object once `var filler = {}`. From that point on, you're just modifying the same object. You can just move that line to inside the `if(years[i] != current)` block to resolve the error.

Comment: `.push(filler)` does not create a copy of the object.

Comment: simplify your code by just doing this: `counter.push({Year:current, Count:cnt});` and remove `filler` altogether. Problem solved.